# Mule ESB, issue when adding up numbers within a JSON array

Tags: json, expression, mule, esb

I use the following dynamic query (even though I could have used a prepared stmt) in my Database COnnection node:

```
SELECT BALANCE FROM xxx.TAB
```

I have the following expression in the SetPayload command that is run immediately after the Datbase Connection node:

```
#[message.payload]
```

and I get the following response from curl:

```
[{"BALANCE":111.11},{"BALANCE":222.12},{"BALANCE":444.30}]
```

So I modify the flow, putting an expression node between the Database connection node and the SetPayload node with the following expressions:

```
sum = 0;
foreach (row : message.payload) {
  sum += row['BALANCE'];
}
message.payload = sum;
```

I run curl again, but this time I get the following:

```
777.5299999999999994315658113919199
```

Actually, the answer should be 777.53

What happened to this data?

Is there a way to fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the value is a Float or Double. Take a look at something like: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Bit messy, but something like:

```
sum = 0;
foreach (row : message.payload) {
  sum += row['BALANCE'];
}
message.payload = new java.text.DecimalFormat("#.##").format(sum);
```